# how config sma to allow access of host with specific name with dynamic ip

Tags: samba

in my case, my guest pc is win10 os, server pc is ubuntu20.04.

my guest win10-pc with a fixed name `win10pc.mynet.com`, with ip like 10.11.12.*, changed every time i restart win10-pc,

my server ubuntu could ping sucessfully with `ping win10pc.mynet.com`, and i wanto control the access of some shared folder with samba, as simple as possible, and following is my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```bash
[global]
map to guest = bad user

[data_share]
comment = share_folder
path = /data/share_folder/
available = yes
browseable = no
writeable = yes
hosts allow = win10pc.mynet.com
guest ok = yes
force user = igs
```

and it does not work as expected, what do i missed?

if i change `hosts allow = 10.11.12.13` instead (assuming 10.11.12.13 is the ip of win10pc this time), then i can accesses server from guest-win10-pc, but this is annoying every time the ip changed.

Comment: Does the DNS remote lookup work (i.e. what does `nslookup 10.11.12.13` say?

Comment: thx for helping, says `** server can't find 13.12.11.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN`

Comment: but with `nslookup win10pc.mynet.com` i got `Server: 127.0.0.53 Address: 127.0.0.53#53` and `Non-authoritative answer: Name: win10pc.mynet.com Address: 10.11.12.13`

Comment: @stoney thanks for more help:)

Comment: Sry for late reply: You have to get your DNS reverse lookups working